# Azure: Can't ping SMTP Server, currently using Gmail SMTP Server for an app deployed using Azure Classic VM

Tags: azure, smtp

Can't ping smtp.gmail.com. I've been using google smtp for email notification and it was working until this moment. The app is deployed using azure vm classic deployment - Windows Server 2012 r2. Firewall is disabled.

I've tried to diagnose using telnet on port 587 but the result is 
"220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP f125sm12740457pfc.91 - gsmtp

Connection to host lost."

telnet smtp.gmail.com 587

220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP f125sm12740457pfc.91 - gsmtp

Connection to host lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

App might have been spamming host and IP banned. You can check IP against blacklist and see.

https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

But Microsoft does not recommend using Azure VM (Service) as SMTP outgoing Mail server, recommendation is to use a mail relay service like sendgrid, smtpgo, etc...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity#recommended-method-of-sending-email

Dead Link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2017/11/15/enhanced-azure-security-for-sending-emails-november-2017-update/